# How to style the input after a user leaves the input

Tags: html, css

I would like to style the input of the user in an `input` element, but I cannot seem to find the right (pseudo) class for it. To clear it up: it's not the `placeholder` I want to style, can do that.

```css
input {
    background-color: white;
}

input::placeholder {
    color: blue;
}

input:active, input:focus {
    color: red;
}

input:pseudo_class? { // When the user leaves the input, styling the text.
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Subscribe to our News Letter">
</div>
```

Comment: so you basically want to add different css after on blur event ?

Comment: Not sure its the right name for it, but when the user leaves the input field and to style the user inputted text. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: @aug, It's not the placeholder I want to change.

Comment: this can only be achieved by javascript/jquery

Comment: @RushabhSheth, well, you can so this JS, but I don't think that is the best way to go about it. But CSS can do what I wanted, see the answer from dippas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just set `color:black` in `input`

```css
input {
  background-color: white;
  color: black
}

input::placeholder {
  color: blue;
}

input:active,
input:focus {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Subscribe to our News Letter">
</div>
```